# C++: Can "try { foo(); } catch (...) { throw; }" be optimized to "foo();"?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-optimization

In C++, is the following code

```
try {
  foo();
} catch (...) {
  throw;
}
```

semantically identical to just calling `foo` like this?

```
foo();
```

If so, can I expect a state-of-the-art compiler to avoid the first version to the second version (when compiling with optimization enabled)?

In other words, if I compile this code with `NDEBUG` and optimizations enabled

```
try {
  foo();
} catch (...) {
  assert(some_check());
  throw;
}
```

can I assume that it should never be slower that this ugly version

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
  try {
#endif
    foo();
#ifndef NDEBUG
  } catch (...) {
    assert(some_check());
    throw;
  }
#endif
```

Comment: [Not in practice.](https://godbolt.org/g/kXdxf6)

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but if nothing inside foo() throws an exception, it's safe to assume the compiler can make this optimization.

Comment: @DeiDei If `foo` can't throw (and the compiler knows this, eg. through `noexcept`), the compiler will remove any related exception handling branches. But the question is more general than that.

Comment: Even `try { throw 0; } catch (...) {}` and `try { throw 0; } catch (...) { throw; }`  seem to generate suboptimal code. Exceptions don't optimize well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two are not equivalent.

Whether the stack is unwound when there is no handler for an exception is implementation-defined ([except.handle]p9). When a handler is there, but it merely re-throws the exception, the stack must be unwound at least up until the point where the exception is re-thrown.

That is:

```
struct S { ~S(); };
void foo() { S s; throw 0; }
int main() {
  try { foo(); }
  catch(...) { throw; }
}
```

This must call `s`'s destructor. When the `try { ... } catch (...) { throw; }` is removed, it is no longer required to call `s`'s destructor.

It's even possible, depending on what `s`'s destructor does, for the execution to never reach the re-throwing of the exception, by adding e.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
S::~S() { exit(0); }
```

Now, the program must run successfully, but when the `try { ... } catch (...) { throw; }` is removed, that's no longer required, and a crash can and does happen on real systems.